# How do I reverse every line and every sentence in a paragraph?

Tags: file-io, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I need to scan a file and then use an array list to reverse each sentene  the code on the line I'm trying to do an arraylist of array list or arrays of array which ever is easier. I should reverse the lines from top to bottom and from left to right for example if the girls read was 
"I can't solve this problem,
I've been at it for two days" after code is executed it should read
"days two for it at been I've
problem, this solve can't I" Teacher hinted to use for each loop? 
I just need the syntax to put the file into array per lines,  then the words in each line into an array. File is a .txt

Comment: Where's the code you've written so far

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If the paragraph is in a string you can just split on "." and pass that array into the constructor of ArrayList after doing Array.asList() on the array. That would give you your array list.</strike> You should do some more research on this.